# Creating Datum Target using Catia VBA

Tags: vba, catia, vba6, caa

I have a question on Drafting side of Catia, I am trying to record creating a datum Target on a view in a drawing. But the recording is unfruitful. I also looked into the documentation and searched the internet but couldn't find a thing on this, while searching I found out that the Datum Target can only be created using the CAA using RADE, but I don't have access to CAA.

Is this true or am I missing something.

below image shows what I am trying to achieve

[image: The Datum Target A1 and A2 is what I want to create using macro, as seen in the image]

Comment: Also please help me out if there is any other way to do this

Comment: Not available as Automation, only CAA. In automation the solution should be to calculate the coordonates of your part acording to the plane of your view, thanks to a Matrix transform calculation. You have the 3d coordonates -> Matrix transform to the plane of your view.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that @Disvoys , extraction of point coordinates from the part is fine but I want to create the Datum targets in the drawing and I am not finding any other way using automation.